# Scroll svg inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have a simple use case. I have an outer div and an svg inside. Like,

```
<div>
  <svg>
     ...
     ...
  </svg>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the svg to scroll inside the div, but without any luck :( I tried setting:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

But it does not work, can you guys help me out? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should post your complete code or create fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

you have to define the container height, otherwise the container height will be adjusted to the svg height.

html:

```
<div>
    <svg viewbox="0 0 400 400">
        <path d="M 200 100 l 100 200 l -200 0 Z" stroke-width="5" stroke="red"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/Lvnozzn2/1/

Comment: this works for fixed height. I would like to have same for div with fixed height and fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

Usually scrolling will show up when you set a size to the div and the content (in your case the svg) overflows the size.  for instance this is the css class that I wrote earlier today that has a scroll bar on it once the content starts overflowing outside the div

```
#outbox_div {
border: 3px solid grey;
border-radius:2px;
height:200px;
width:80%;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would mark the div as overflow:scroll.

This way, as the svg component grows the div will scroll fit it.

When using svg components I always put them inside their own div to compartmentalize the graphics code from the rest of the page.

Comment: Thanks, I set the overflow on the outer div to scroll (corrected question). The width of both the outer div and the svg are set to 100%. It does not seem to work.

Comment: Do not set size on the svg. This will stop the svg from going larger than its containing div.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking to get horizontal scrolling to work, the svg needs a specific **css** width in pixels and the containing element eg a div needs overflow:scroll or similar.

We had a dynamic svg built at runtime so we set this at runtime eg:

```
<div class="container">
  <svg></svg>
</div>

<style>
.container {
  overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
```

and some code to determine the width at runtime and set this as a css property

```
var $svg = $("svg"),
    bBox = $svg[0].getBBox();
$svg.css("width", bBox.width + "px");
```

so it effectively ends up being something like:

```
<div class="container" style="overflow:scroll">
  <svg style="width:123px;"></svg>
</div>
```